# !is_page_template not working with && operator

Tags: page-template

On single custom post types using the `single-course.php` template I want a different breadcrumb option to happen, but it's not obeying the `&&` operator in the if statement:

```
<?php if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') && !is_page_template( 'single-course.php' ) ) {
    yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>');
} else { ?>
    <p id="breadcrumbs"><span xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#"><span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Home</a> » <span rel="v:child" typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a href="<?php echo site_url('/tracks'); ?>" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Tracks</a> » <strong class="breadcrumb_last"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></strong></span></span></span></p>
<?php } ?>
```

This is a template piece that is called in the `single-course.php` template (and others) after the loop:

```
    <main class="main" role="main">
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('templates/page', 'header'); ?>
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: `is_page() && !is_page_template( 'single-course.php' )` ?

Comment: thanks, that worked: used this `if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') && is_page() && !is_page_template( 'single-course.php' ) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include [`is_page()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) in your if statement :

```
<?php if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') && is_page() && !is_page_template( 'single-course.php' ) ) {
    yoast_breadcrumb('<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>');
} else { ?>
    <p id="breadcrumbs"><span xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#"><span typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Home</a> » <span rel="v:child" typeof="v:Breadcrumb"><a href="<?php echo site_url('/tracks'); ?>" rel="v:url" property="v:title">Tracks</a> » <strong class="breadcrumb_last"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></strong></span></span></span></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> On **single custom post types** using the single-course.php template I want a different breadcrumb option to happen

[`is_page_template`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.2.2/wp-includes/post-template.php#L1664-L1665) will not work on non-pages. If you're looking to tell if you're on a single custom post type page, you should use [`is_singular`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) and pass in the custom post type name:

```
if (function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') && !is_singular('course')) {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

On important note here: if `yoast_breadcrumb` doesn't exist you will get your alternative breadcrumbs on every page, not just on singular course pages.

Comment: sounds like that would work but doesn't. tried both `is_singular` and `is_single` options. `if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') && !is_singular( 'single-course.php' ) ) {`